# Disabling X-FRAME-OPTION: SAMEORIGIN HTTP Response Header on SharePoint/PowerPivot xlsviewer.aspx

Tags: sharepoint, http, powerpivot, x-frame-options

I need to frame a page being served by SharePoint 2010's `xlsviewer.aspx` but this page is setting the HTTP response header `X-FRAME-OPTION` to `SAMEORIGIN`, so IE8 refuses to render the page in a frame on another domain, which is what I need.

It appears that no other pages being served by this SharePoint instance set `X-FRAME-OPTIONS`, only `_layouts/xlsviewer.aspx`

Where can I change the HTTP headers or framing options for SharePoint or this specific page?

Relevant headers:

```
GET //_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=whatever.xlsx&DefaultItemOpen=1
```

is returning:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
. . .
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.4730
```

Answer (score 1):

Got to your Sharepoint Admin  -> Manager Service Applications - > Excel Service Application ->Global Settings-> Check Allow Cross Domain Access